# jQuery version of Dojo's Stateful?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dojo, stateful

Does anyone know of any plugins written in jQuery that are similar to [Dojo's Stateful](http://www.dojotoolkit.org/api/dojo/Stateful.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not as far as I know. Dojo's stateful relies on very little Dojo. One removal of dojo.declare and a change of dojo.indexOf to $.inArray and it's done.

http://github.com/phiggins42/bloody-jquery-plugins/blob/master/Stateful.js

Comment: worth noting that the above assumes the global `console` is available, and is used in error callbacks and whatnot. In Dojo, we do a if(window.console)ish thing, so it's safe, but you may need an additional jquery plugin to ensure those calls won't break in production (or just change the code, which is a pita)